# Deselect vertices with another mesh

Tags: modeling, vertices, select

I made a non-manifold selection, to select my border, but I don't need the entire selection. To automatize my flow, I wish to deselect the "nonuseful" vertices with another mesh.
The intention is to position every kind of mesh on this "Deselection mesh" and deselect the vertices inside. Is it possible?

Comment: I assume circular/box/lasso deselect didnt bring you the effort you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a simpler solution is possible (or automating the below steps), but here's what I came up with.

- **base** - the mesh you're working on
- **selector** - the mesh you want to use for (de)selecting
- **copy** - the copy of **base** created in step 1.

[image]

1. Duplicate the **base** which now becomes the **copy**, add a **Boolean** modifier in **Intersection** mode and choose **selector** as a target. Apply the modifier.

[image]

2. Hide the **selector**.

[image]

3. Select all vertices of the **copy** and **assign** them to a new vertex group.

[image]

4. Select the **copy** in *Object Mode*, then the **base** (so the **base** is *active*), and switch from *Object Mode* to *Weight Paint*:

[image]

5. From *Weights* menu choose **Transfer Weights**.

[image]

6. Expand the panel that pops up in bottom-left corner:

[image]

7. Set *Data Type* to **Vertex Groups**.

[image]

8. Select **Only Neighbor Geometry** and decrease the **Max Distance** to the smallest non-zero value (try `0.00001`)

[image]

9. Go back to *Object Mode*, remove the **copy**. Start editing the **base**:

[image]

10. You can now select the part shared with the **selector**:

[image] [image]

11. Or make a selection:

[image]

12. And deselect the part shared with the **selector**:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: i like the creativity in that one :D